# How do I change the file permission to be able to write over a file using Netbeans?

Tags: files

I am trying to edit a file and when I open it using Netbeans IDE, I am not able to edit is as it is only a read-only file. I am able to edit using the GEdit Text editor and by running the command

```
sudo gedit file.cpp
```

which opens the text editor and allows me to make changes but I prefer to use the Netbeans IDE at the moment since I am not familiar with using vim.

Comment: Can you save the file with gedit? What is the output of `ls -l file.cpp`?

Comment: I used the command sudo chmod a+rwx <file> and was able to edit the file after in Netbeans.